# Dart: Uncaught Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 7: 7

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two list. I want which data not matching from list2 then list2 data add in list3 with num : list2 Data and name "z"

```
void main() {
   List list1 = [
    {"num": 1, "name": "a"},
    {"num": 2, "name": "b"},
    {"num": 2, "name": "b"},
    {"num": 3, "name": "c"},
    {"num": 3, "name": "c"},
    {"num": 4, "name": "d"},
    {"num": 5, "name": "e"},
    {"num": 6, "name": "f"},
    {"num": 6, "name": "f"},
    {"num": 7, "name": "g"},
    {"num": 8, "name": "h"},
    {"num": 9, "name": "i"},
    {"num": 10, "name": "j"},
    {"num": 10, "name": "j"},
  ];

  List list2 = [1, 3, 10, 30, 40, 50, 60];

  List list3 = [];
  for (int i = 0; i <= list2.length; i++) {
    list1.forEach((data) {
      if (data["num"] == list2[i]) {
        list3.add(data);
      }
    });
    list3.add({"num": list2[i], "name": "Z"});
  }
  print(list3);
}
```

I want output like this as list3

```
[
    {"num": 1, "name": "a"},
    {"num": 2, "name": "b"},
    {"num": 2, "name": "b"},
    {"num": 3, "name": "c"},
    {"num": 3, "name": "c"},
    {"num": 4, "name": "d"},
    {"num": 5, "name": "e"},
    {"num": 6, "name": "f"},
    {"num": 6, "name": "f"},
    {"num": 7, "name": "g"},
    {"num": 8, "name": "h"},
    {"num": 9, "name": "i"},
    {"num": 10, "name": "j"},
    {"num": 10, "name": "j"},
    {"num": 30, "name": "z"},
    {"num": 40, "name": "z"},
    {"num": 50, "name": "z"},
    {"num": 60, "name": "z"},
  ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `i < list2.length`

```
void main() {
  List list1 = [
    {"num": 1, "name": "a"},
    {"num": 2, "name": "b"},
    {"num": 2, "name": "b"},
    {"num": 3, "name": "c"},
    {"num": 3, "name": "c"},
    {"num": 4, "name": "d"},
    {"num": 5, "name": "e"},
    {"num": 6, "name": "f"},
    {"num": 6, "name": "f"},
    {"num": 7, "name": "g"},
    {"num": 8, "name": "h"},
    {"num": 9, "name": "i"},
    {"num": 10, "name": "j"},
    {"num": 10, "name": "j"},
  ];

  List list2 = [1, 3, 10, 30, 40, 50, 60];

  List list3 = [];
  final setList1 = Set<int>();
  list1.forEach((data) {
    setList1.add(data['num']);
    list3.add(data);
  });

  for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
    if (!setList1.contains(list2[i])) {
      list3.add({"num": list2[i], "name": "Z"});
    }
  }
  print(list3);
}
```

Comment: error resolved but Output not coming proper

Comment: @Deepak I just updated answer